# echo get_theme_mod('footer_background'); the code shows up instead of the value

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, echo

I'm customizing my Customization options in a WordPress theme following a video from awfulmedia (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XloM1F5M2fU). It's very good, but I've got one hang up.

```
function martinStart_footer_customizer_register($wp_customize) {
    $wp_customize->add_section('footer_styles', array(
        'title' => __('Footer Styles', 'martinStart'),
        'description' => 'Modify Footer Styles'
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_setting('footer_background', array(
        'default' => '#CCC',
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize, 'footer_background_ctrl', array(
        'label' => __('Footer Background Color', 'martinStart'),
        'section' => 'footer_styles',
        'settings' => 'footer_background'
    ) ));
}

function martinStart_footer_style() {
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .site-footer {background-color: <$php echo get_theme_mod('footer_background'); ?>;}
    </style>
    <?php
}

add_action('wp_head', 'martinStart_footer_style');
add_action('customize_register', 'martinStart_footer_customizer_register');
```

So I use the Wordpress custom_color_control and the color change is saved in the wp_options table, and style declaration is added to the head.

But the value isn't added, it writes the php code! Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

php code most be surrounded by `<?php code ?>`, but the code in question begins with `<$php`. You need to replace the $ with a ?.

Comment: Thank you so much! I suspected it was some sort of typo. I scoured the code, but never saw the $! All better now.